# PyCrypto Sign Message and Verify Signature in .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: .net, cryptography, digital-signature, pycrypto, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to create a signature verification system that uses my website which runs on the Google API with PyCrypto Engine.
The program that generates signature is quite simple:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
def sign(key, message):
   digest = MD5.new(message).digest()
   signature = key.sign( digest, None )[0]
   signature = hex(signature).replace("0x","").replace("L","").upper()
   if len(signature) % 2==1:
      signature = "0" + sig 
   return signature
```

The key 'key' is provided by:

```
RSA.construct((m, e, d, p, q))
```

The signature is returned as a hex string, such as: "A12D......."

.NET program is:

```
    Private Function Verify(ByVal message As String, ByVal sign As String) As Boolean
    Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim f As New StreamReader("D:/KEY.XML")
    Dim xml As String = f.ReadToEnd
    f.Close()

    Dim rsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider
    rsa.FromXmlString(xml)

    Dim msg_as_bytes As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message)
    Dim hash_as_bytes As Byte() = md5.ComputeHash(msg_as_bytes)

    ''Dim sig_as_bytes As Byte() = convtobytes(sign)

    Dim sig_as_bytes As Byte() = New Byte(sign.Length / 2 - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 1 To sign.Length / 2
        sig_as_bytes(i - 1) = CByte("&H" & Mid(sign, (i - 1) * 2 + 1, 2))
    Next

    Return rsa.VerifyData(hash_as_bytes, "SHA1", sig_as_bytes)
End Function
```

But it does not work!!! Why??

Pycrypto and .NET receive the same parameters (modulus, exponent, d, p, q)

Answer (score 4):

I finished!

The solution is to use Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util import number
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

m = 123....
e = 1111....
d = 123....
p = 365...
q = 657...

key = RSA.construct((m, e, d, p, q))

message = "message to be signed"

def assina(message):
    h = SHA.new(message)
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    signature = signer.sign(h)
    return ByteToHex(signature)
```

And .NET code to verify:

```
Private Function Verify(ByVal message As String, ByVal sign As String) As Boolean
    Dim rsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
    rsa.FromXmlString(_pubKey)

    Dim msg_as_bytes As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message)

    Dim sig_as_bytes As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(sign.Length / 2) - 1) {}

    For i As Integer = 1 To sign.Length / 2
        sig_as_bytes(i - 1) = CByte("&H" & Mid(sign, (i - 1) * 2 + 1, 2))
    Next

    Return rsa.VerifyData(msg_as_bytes, "SHA", sig_as_bytes)
End Function
```

Comment: You can also use `Crypto.Hash.SHA256` in Python, and `rsa.VerifyData(msg_as_bytes, "SHA256", sig_as_bytes)` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Look at both lines:

> digest = MD5.new(message).digest()
>
> Return rsa.VerifyData(hash_as_bytes, "SHA1", sig_as_bytes)

Even if you're using a `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` in your .NET code your still asking the verification to use `SHA1` and that won't work. Try changing this to `MD5`.

Comment: not work...
 rsa.VerifyData(hash_as_bytes, "MD5", sig_as_bytes)

Comment: BitConverter.ToString(rsa.SignData(hash_as_bytes, "MD5")).Replace("-", "") not equal of value returned by python function ....

Comment: Digital signature using RSA use padding (e.g. PKCS#1 or OAEP) which includes random data. As such you cannot expect the same value out of `SignData`

Comment: ok, so why the program. NET does not return TRUE as expected?
.NET fix: rsa.VerifyData (hash_as_bytes, "MD5", sig_as_bytes)

Comment: I made this changes, but not work, and signatures in pycrypto and .net not equal...

Comment: That simply means it was not the **only** error you had. I can't help you with python (nor much vb.net) but make sure your padding (PKCS1 or OAEP) are identical and that your hash values are also identical (otherwise your signature validation will never work).

Comment: @poupou, Hello, I've been having a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329147/trying-to-generate-rsa-signature-with-python-from-working-c-sharp-code/10332841#10332841. I was wondering if you wouldn't mind helping. Thanks !

Comment: Hello, I have post this link with the problem: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26155911/pythonSignNetVerify.zip
It has a version of the two codes for a better understanding

Comment: Better to use `SHA256` in both Python and C#.